# ConvertAPI - PDF to PPT in C#

Tags: c#, convertapi

We were upgrading to the new logic specified by ConvertAPI. But the framework used by us is 4 because of which  `System.Net.Http(HttpResponseMessage`, `HttpClient` ,`MultipartFormDataContent` ,`StreamContent` ,`StringContent`) classes are not being found. Even added `System.Net.Http` reference. But still the same error persists.
Can someone suggest some workaround for this? How to use ConvertApi in C# for .Net Framework 4?

Comment: Could you post whole C# code?

Comment: Before we had `HttpClient` people used `WebClient`, which has been around since .Net 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use WebClient instead of HttpClient for quick file upload. To run the demo below you will need to replace file paths and set your secret instead of **xxxxx** in endpoint url. Also we should set `accept:application/octet-stream` header to get response as data stream instead of json.

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            
            const string fileToConvert = @"C:\Projects\_temp\test1.docx";
            const string fileToSave = @"C:\Projects\_temp\test1.pdf";            

            try
            {
                using (var client = new WebClient())
                {
                    client.Headers.Add("accept", "application/octet-stream");
                    var resultFile = client.UploadFile(new Uri("https://v2.convertapi.com/docx/to/pdf?Secret=xxxxx"), fileToConvert); 
                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileToSave, resultFile );
                    Console.WriteLine("File converted successfully");
                }
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
                Console.WriteLine("Body : {0}", new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd());
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```